# using #request.requestURI.equals() in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am new in Spring Boot, please don't be angry...

If I have a link: "http://localhost:8080/menu" and with what I have coded, I can highlight  tag. But when I transfer to another URL, of course it will not work anymore. Is there a way to maintain activating  tag if new URLs will look like this? : http://localhost:8080/menu/new/.../new99

`<a class="nav-link" th:classappend="${#request.requestURI.equals('/menu')}? 'active': ''" href="/board/boardList?list=5">menu</a>`

I really cannot think something better than this. Sorry...

Comment: do you mean the visited css style for urls ?

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to code and with the visited css style. I haven't thought of that!

Comment: if the visited css style you mean then I'm not sure if it is possible because the behavior of the visited url is define by browser so the url you provide will be mark as different http://localhost:8080/menu is different from http://localhost:8080/menu/new/.../new99

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.